# Invoke-Command doesn't run the bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am rolling out a script for an unattended installation, I have built a small .bat for the Office 2019 installation and when I run it it works perfectly but when I call it through the PowerShell Script the installation does not run.

Any ideas?

This is the portion of the code

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\Office2019\Install-32.bat" -ArgumentList "--quiet" -Verb RunAs -Wait}
```

.bat file

```
setup.exe /configure configuration-x86.xml
```

Office Config File

```
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="32">
    <Product ID="ProPlus2019Volume" PIDKEY="MYKEY">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE"/>
  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1"/>
</Configuration>
```

Thank you so much for any advise.

Comment: I don’t think you can use an argument list for calling a bat file. You’d have to specify in the bat file itself to do a silent install. 

Or instead of using a bat file you can just call ``setup.exe -argumentlist “/configure $xmlfile /q” -wait``

Answer (score 0):

Bat files can only be interpreted by the OS shell, which is the cmd.exe. Your file path needs to be changed as follow:

cmd.exe /c c:\temp\Office2019\Install-32.bat

Powershell won’t interpret bat files, it only runs exe files and commands.

Comment: Hello Digger, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

In fact it already solved the problem. This was in that I need to define the working directory for the execution of the bath file, in the end the sentence was like this: 

{
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -WorkingDirectory "c:\temp\Office2019\" -FilePath "c:\temp\Office2019\Install-32.bat" -Wait -Verb RunAs}
}

Thank you so much.